# designing my ticket api

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a function named getTicket which take two argument id which is a number and format (string)

```
def getTicket(id, format):
    if format == "pdf":
        getTicketPDF(id) #some specialized pdf method gets called
    elif format == "json":
        getTicketJSON(id) #specialized json method
```

Now if I have to support some new format like "html" then I can create another elif for html.

But I want to generalize this code so that if in future n new method gets added I do not have to change my code

How can I design my getTicket api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that stores the `format` to function mapping , like `"pdf"` mapping to function `getTicketPDF` , etc. And then in your `getTicket()` function you call the dictionary's value for `format` and call it by passing `id` parameter to it. Example -

```
funcdict = {"pdf":getTicketPDF
           "json":getTicketJSON}
def getTicket(id, format):
    try:
        funcdict[format](id)
    except KeyError:
        #Handle case where format is not found in dictionary
```

If later you decide to add a new function for a new format, you just need to add a new mapping to the dictionary.

Comment: Just wondering whether it is possible that I can have some kind of run time polymorphism to detect the type and call subsequent api?

Comment: Hmm, what kind of runtime polymorphism are you thinking about?

Comment: I was thinking to inherit getTicketPDF and getTicketJSON from getTicket but that will also need to keep if condn...the answer you mentioned seems to satisfy my requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case calls for a Strategy Pattern Implementation(PDF/JSON/HTML ticket generation strategies) which uses a Factory Pattern to obtain the correct strategy implementation class.
Here are the high-level steps -

1. Separate the functionality of ticket generation into a class TicketGenerator. Let this be an interface. It will have a single abstract method generateTicket()
2. Use a TicketGeneratorFactory to get the correct TicketGenerator instance based on the type of ticket i.e. an instance of PDFTicketGenerator, JSONTicketGenerator, HTMLTicketGenerator and so on... Each of these implemention classes have a generateTicket() implementation as per the type i.e. PDF/JSON/HTML.
3. This instance should be assigned to the base TicketGenerator Type.
4. TicketGenerator.generateTicket() would then give you the ticket in the desired format - PDF/JSON/HTML.